Use a filter in a google sheet to show the latest order from each customer
If you have an array of data in a google sheet containing the columns:-

Customer ID

Date of order

Product

Cost


Is there a way of using a filter to show only rows containing the latest order from each customer?
I somehow think there might be a simple answer, but it is escaping me.
I tried searching for existing solutions, but couldn't find one.

You could use something like this :
=CHOOSEROWS(QUERY(A1:D;"SELECT * WHERE A <> '' ORDER BY A ASC, B ASC");1;ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(UNIQUE(QUERY(A2:D;"select Col1 WHERE Col1 <> ''"));QUERY(QUERY(A1:D;"SELECT * ORDER BY A ASC, B ASC");"select Col1 WHERE Col1 <> ''");1)))

First you get the list of IDs with UNIQUE.
Then, you look for each ID in the array which has been sorted (by IDs and date). Note you have "1" instead of "0" at the end of MATCH to look for the last ID occurence (~ the last order). To finish, you use CHOOSEROWS to select the rows of interest with the indexes previously found during the MATCH step.
The formula should work with sorted (or not sorted) array + "growing" array.


or sort it:
=SORTN(SORT(A2:D, ROW(A2:A), 0), 9^9, 2, 1, 1)



sort A2:D range
by ROW(A2:A) row numbers
in 0 descending order
then SORTN it
return all 9^9 rows
use mode 2 to merge duplicates
of first 1 column
in 1 ascending order

